# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value did not match expected type java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: hibernate, datetime, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jsonserializer

I just started to take care of a code developed by other person. It was designed based on Specification pattern using Spring Data and Hibernate.

In few words, if I try search using string, boolean or integer fields it works correctly. For instance, when I search/filter with state==SP I got the result and I can see that the diatomite fields are correctly filled in. Also I see hibernate no complaining about invalid data in this case:

Copied form my console when I searched succesfully with "state==SP"
    ...
    TRACE 2450 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([created17_12_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2013-07-12T06:53:47]
    ...

[image]

Nevertheless, when I search/filter with datetime I get the error summarised in this question. For instance: I search "createdDate==2014-06-03T18:48:33" and I get:

```
2018-03-23 17:38:17.547 ERROR 2450 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2014-06-03T18:48:33] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2014-06-03T18:48:33] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2014-06-03T18:48:33] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:897) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:638) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaCompiler.java:109) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:366) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:130) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:699) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:656) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:608) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:407) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at br.com.moving.service.ApiServiceImpl.list(ApiServiceImpl.java:48)
```

[image]

The repository raising error when calling findAll:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ApiServiceImpl implements ApiService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public <T> Page<T> list(Class<T> clazz, Class<? extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>> clazz2, String search,
            Pageable pageable, Class<? extends Specification<T>> specClazz) {
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> repository = new JpaRepositoryFactory(em).getRepository(clazz2);

        SpecificationBuilder<T> builder = new SpecificationBuilder<>(specClazz);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+.*?)(==|!=|<|<=|>|>=|=|===)((\\*|\\w+).*?);");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search + ";");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            builder.with(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
        }

        org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<T> spec = builder.build();
        Page<T> page = repository.findAll(spec, pageable);

        return page;
    }
...
```

ApiService interface

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

import br.com.mycompany.specification.Specification;

public interface ApiService {

    <T> Page<T> list(Class<T> clazz, Class<? extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>> clazz2, String search, Pageable pageable, Class<? extends Specification<T>> customSpec);

    <T> T get(Class<T> clazz, Class<? extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>> clazz2, String search, Class<? extends Specification<T>> customSpec);
}
```

LocalDateTimeSerializer:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;

    public class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDateTime dateTime, JsonGenerator generator,
                com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException {
            if (dateTime == null) {
                generator.writeNull();
            } else {
                generator.writeString(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")));
            }
        }

}
```

Model:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import br.com.mycompany.converter.BooleanNumberConverter;
import br.com.mycompany.converter.ReleaseCategoryTypeConverter;
import br.com.mycompany.converter.ReleaseStatusTypeConverter;
import br.com.mycompany.serializer.LocalDateTimeSerializer;


@Entity
@Table(name = "releases")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Release implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "state", length = 2)
    private String state;

    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();

//other fields, constructors, gets/sets not relevant
```

The database is Mysql. If I search straigh in MySql via Workbench I can see this sample:

```
select created_date from releases

'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
...
'2013-09-28 09:19:23'
'2013-09-28 09:19:59'
```

By locking close the format it seems to me that LocalDateTimeSerializer.serialize is correct.

Any clue will be highly appreciated.

**** edited

After read carefully [Hibernate 4 with java.time.LocalDate and DATE() construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890687/hibernate-4-with-java-time-localdate-and-date-construct), I checked which jar versions I have and, as far as I can see, I didn't find any tip if there is a problem with my jars. I added below two print screen which reveals which jar versions I am using.
 Additionally, I am pasting bellow the three approaches used. All three resulted in same error explained above.

Libraries:

[image]

and

[image]

Approaches used with no difference at all:

1 - removed @JsonSerialize and @Converter from column. I mean:

```
//@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
//@Convert(converter = MovingLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

2 - added JsonSerialize. I mean:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;

public class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime dateTime, JsonGenerator generator,
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException {
        if (dateTime == null) {
            generator.writeNull();
        } else {
            generator.writeString(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")));
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

3 - added converter. I mean,

```
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class MovingLocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, String> {

    //private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime value) {
        return (value != null) ? value.format(fmt) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        return convertLocalDateTime(value);
    }

    private LocalDateTime convertLocalDateTime(String value) {
        try {
            return (value != null) ? LocalDateTime.parse(value.substring(0, 19), fmt) : null;
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
@Convert(converter = MovingLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

All tentatives didn't change at all the current error.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue, did you resolve the problem?
If so, could you share the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to add below dependency. For more info please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29542062/5296354)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. I am still getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2014-06-03T18:48:33] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:897) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]"

Comment: Have you removed your `LocalDateTimeSerializer`?

Comment: Yes, I removed it from all java.time.LocalDateTime (I have three fields). I am still getting exactly same error. I am reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890687/hibernate-4-with-java-time-localdate-and-date-construct carefully but I don't see whittles I can do. additionally, it is interesting that there is no answer chose for this question.